# PowerShell pyramid

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner at this so pleas don't be offended by this question. I need to write a PowerShell program in which a user inputs a number and the program draws a pyramid of `*`. So if the user inputs `5` the program displays:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

So far I have managed to make only the right part of the pyramid. This is the code.

```
$x = [int] (Read-Host "Write number")
for($i=1; $i -le $x; $i++) {
    for($k=1; $k -le $x; $k++ ){
        Write-Host -NoNewLine " "
    }
    for($j=1; $j -le 2 * $i - 1; $j++) {
        Write-Host -NoNewLine "*"
    }
    Write-Host " "
}
```

And it displays:

```
     * 
     *** 
     ***** 
     ******* 
     *********
```

I haven't found anything similar on the internet, so if anyone could please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a shorthand version; probably too early in your PowerShell career to be useful; but an idea of what's possible as you learn the language: `$x = 5; 1..$x | %{' ' * ($x-$_) + '*' * ($_ * 2 - 1)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code as written using 5 as the input you get each line printed with 5 spaces in front of it.

If you change your code to this:

```
$x = [int] (Read-Host "Write number") 
for($i=1; $i -le $x; $i++){ 
   #changed -le $x to -le $x - $i
   for($k=1; $k -le $x -$i; $k++ ){
      Write-Host -NoNewLine " "
   }

   for($j=1; $j -le 2 * $i - 1; $j++){ 
     Write-Host -NoNewLine "*" 
   }

   Write-Host " "
}
```

Then the output when entering 5 will be:

```
    * 
   *** 
  ***** 
 ******* 
*********
```

Which I believe is what you want.

Comment: @Novice: If emanresu's answer solved your issue, please mark this answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

to reverse the pyramid use this:

```
[int32]$x = read-host "write number"

for($i=1; $i -le $x; $i++){ 
   for($k=1; $k -lt $i; $k++ ){
      Write-Host -NoNewLine " "
   }

   for($j=1; $j -le ($x *2) - ($k *2) +1 ; $j++){ 
     Write-Host -NoNewLine "*" 
   }

   Write-Host "`r"
}
```